# Calling div run at server from backend not working with update panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I built the search logic with textbox search. However, While I search and the query is being executed I want the spinner to run while the results are fetched.

Here's my code : -

I tried both way but the spinner does not show.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Inherit" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Searchtext" OnTextChanged="Searchtext_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
        <div id="spinner" runat="server">
        <img src="././spinner.gif/>
        <div>
        </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>



    <script type="text/javascript">
             function show()
            {
                $('#spinner').css("display", "block");
            }
</script>

    protected void Searchtext_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          spinner.Visible = true;
      searchLogic();
      spinner.Visible = false;

    }
```

Other way : -

```
 <div id="spinner" style="display:none;">
            <img src="././spinner.gif/>
            <div>

public void searchLogic()
    {
        sqlLogic(); // Queries and Results
    }

    protected void Searchtext_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "MyFunction", "show()", true);
      searchLogic(); 

    }
```

If I set run at server or not, when I search it shows waiting in chrome. But spinner is not fired. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The script will be triggered once the call has come back from the method. Meaning it will be triggered after SearchLogic has finished. You have to handle the spinner on clientside before sending the request. And stop it once it has come back.

Comment: Any other way I could establish?

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan Why is doesn't work with visible property before and after?

Comment: You have to understand how to server and client works. If you send a request to the server you are disconnected. Meaning changing anything in the single call like visible true/false will not directly be showing on the clientside. It will apply only once the call has returned. Thats why i told you you have to handle it clientside and not server side.

Comment: Okay. I understand. Could you give me a sample code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the best way to solve it using `Asp:UpdateProgress` and I solved it.
Thanks op's.